# Sort array of file lines by alphabetical

Tags: php, file, sorting

I'm reading a text file of email addresses and outputting the domain only (with the @ symbol). I need to alphabetize the list and then output to display on screen

Here is my code thus far:

```
<?php

    $file_handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
        $line = fgets($file_handle);
        $parts = explode("@", $line);
        $Id = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
        echo "@" . $Id . "<br>";

    }

    fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

How can I initiate a sort to alphabetize the list?

Comment: Can you please give us an example of the file and your current + expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just get every line of the file with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). Then I go through each line with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) where I only return the domain into the array `$lines`. At the end I sort the array with [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) and print it)

```
<?php

    $lines = array_map(function($v){
        return "@" . explode("@", $v)[1];
    }, file("test.txt"));

    sort($lines);

    foreach($lines as $line)
        echo $line . "<br />";

?>
```

Example input/output:

```
a.b@x.com
a.c@a.de
e.s@b.cu
```

```
@a.de 
@b.cu
@x.com
```